# /gazebo/set_physics_properties question (be resolved)

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All:

After Ros Installation, run: roslaunch gazebo_ros empty_world.launch

**terminal info:**

```
setting /run_id to 035b34fe-5738-11e7-8b85-c8ff280e1705
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [5634]
started core service [/rosout]
process[gazebo-2]: started with pid [5641]
process[gazebo_gui-3]: started with pid [5656]
[ INFO] [1498128374.802678518]: Finished loading Gazebo ROS API Plugin.
[ INFO] [1498128374.802975494]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...
```

It does not run ...just waiting.....

Running Ros kinetic under Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

How to fix it?

Thanks.

update:
when I disconnect the wifi, it shows different info:

```
[ INFO] [1498151738.878216601]: Finished loading Gazebo ROS API Plugin.
[ INFO] [1498151738.878562714]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...
Error [parser.cc:581] Unable to find uri[model://sun]
Error [parser.cc:581] Unable to find uri[model://ground_plane]
[ INFO] [1498151739.745098328, 0.021000000]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] is now available.
[ INFO] [1498151739.768749482, 0.044000000]: Physics dynamic reconfigure ready.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264473//gazebo/set_physics_properties-question-(be-resolved)/) by [K03059164](https://answers.ros.org/users/30775/k03059164/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2017-06-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe you can through [here](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5971/how-do-you-completely-uninstall-old-versions-of-gazebo/) to resolve the problem when having the same one.

**The reason is gazebo will be download some models from the internet when first installing.** So, please pay more attention to your first installing Ros.

---

Originally posted by [K03059164](https://answers.ros.org/users/30775/k03059164/) with karma: 36 on 2017-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2